# How to make the frame axes and frame labels/numbers look darker?

Tags: plotting, graphics

For example, take this mathematica generated figure:

[image]

As you can see, the frame edges and frame label are always a bit too "gray-ish" by default. This makes the figures not look crisp. How can I make the edges and labels darker and more like a publication-worthy plot?

Comment: `FrameStyle -> Black`?

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize it was that simple.